# Can Excel 2010 Cell Formula Reference Another Cell For A Portion Of The First Formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Perhaps this is not doable, but all I can do is ask.
I am using MS Excel 2010.  I am going to greatly simplify the issue.

I have a column of many, many cells that all contain the same, very large, IF type of formula.

Ex: Cells K1 thru K3 contain =IF(VeryLargeConditionalFormula1,IF(VeryLargeConditionalFormula2,"It is happening.","Still not gonna happen."),"Not gonna happen.")

Sometimes I find I may need to tweak VeryLargeConditionalFormula1 or VeryLargeConditionalFormula2.  Without wanting to have to manually update each of the Kn cell formulas, or do a global change (which could be dangerous), is there a way to place the text for VeryLargeConditionalFormula1 into L1, and VeryLargeConditionalFormula2 into M1, and then have the Kn cell formula pull in that L1 and M1 text to be included as part of the Kn formula?  This would then only require my tweaking one, or two, cells in order to affect the formulas for many cells.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the calculations for the VeryLargeConditionalFormula1 into A1, the VeryLargeConditionalFormula2 into B1. They will produce either TRUE or FALSE if they just contain a conditon like `=1=1` (not so complex a formula, but still). Now you can use in K1

```
=IF(A1,IF(B1,"it is happening","still not gonna happen"),"not gonna happen")
```

When this formula is copied down it will refer to A2 and B2, unless you use an absolute reference, like this. This will always look at A1 and B1 if the formula is copied down.

```
=IF($A$1,IF($B$1,"it is happening","still not gonna happen"),"not gonna happen")
```

You can then fine tune VeryLargeConditionalFormula1 and VeryLargeConditionalFormula2 separately.